# what html code can i use the make this api info functional(i have the api code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

// "convert" endpoint - convert any amount from one currency to another
// using real-time exchange rates

http://apilayer.net/api/convert

```
? access_key = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
& from = USD
& to = EUR
& amount = 25
& format = 1
```

// append an additional "date" parameter if you want to use
// historical rates for your conversion

```
& date = YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: You can't do it only using html, you will have to use at least javascript, you'll need an access key and a language that allows you to make http requests.

Comment: can you show me an example?